# Android : can't add view programmatically in linearLayout android

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

i have fragment that has scrollview as a parent of layout and in scrollview i have a LinearLayout . when i'm trying to programmatically add view to that LinearLayout but i get the error " The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

this is my layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
tools:context="ir.pnuopen5.application.fragment.LeaugeFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_LeagueFragment_title_lastNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/last_news"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_LeagueFragment_title_lastNews"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_LeagueFragment_lastNews"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    ...
```

and this is my java code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leauge, container, false);

    ...

    LinearLayout newsListView = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_LeagueFragment_lastNews);
    View newsListRow;
    TextView title,time;


    for (int i = 0;i<newsList.size();i++){
        newsListRow  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news_row0, container, false);
        title = (TextView)newsListRow.findViewById(R.id.rowNewsTitle);
        time = (TextView)newsListRow.findViewById(R.id.rowNewsTime);
        title.setText(newsList.get(i).getTitle());
        time.setText(newsList.get(i).getTime());
        newsListView.addView(newsListView);
    }

    ...

    return view;
}
```

Comment: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news_row0, container, false);` => `container`? not `newsListView`? `newsListView.addView(newsListView);` <= seriously you wana add view to itself?  also use ListView instead

Comment: newsListView.addView(newsListView); ??!!

Comment: @Selvin i'm need a something like listview but that shouldn't be scrollable

Comment: before adding the view , remove it by calling `newsListView.removeView(view);`

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani ohhh ! This was causing the problems. ! Thank you for your help

Comment: @user2549089 Your welcome ;) I posted the answer please accept and vote it ;)

Comment: typo in the last line of your for loop should be `newsListView.addView(newsListRow);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code snippet `newsListView.addView(newsListView)`, you are adding a view to itself. I think what you meant to do was:

```
newsListView.addView(newsListRow);
```

...to put it back in context...

```
for (int i = 0;i<newsList.size();i++){
    newsListRow  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news_row0, container, false);
    title = (TextView)newsListRow.findViewById(R.id.rowNewsTitle);
    time = (TextView)newsListRow.findViewById(R.id.rowNewsTime);
    title.setText(newsList.get(i).getTitle());
    time.setText(newsList.get(i).getTime());
    newsListView.addView(newsListRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you get that error. Look you are inflating an View, for first time when your loop runs it adds that view in your linear layout. When next time your loop runs it takes the same object of that view which you have previously added. As this is a static view it wont create a new object when you initialize it.

You should use dynamic View.

Following is your answer

```
    for(int i = 0;i<newsList.size();i++) {
        LinearLayout newsListRow  = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        TextView time = new TextView(this);

        title.setText(newsList.get(i).getTitle());
        time.setText(newsList.get(i).getTime());

        newsListRow.addView(title);
        newsListRow.addView(time);

        newsListView.addView(newsListView);
    }
```

You can add LayoutParameter to make it look like your static row view.

That's it... Enjoy... :-)

Comment: Actually inflating the same xml in a loop WILL create a new object each time. It's not necessary to do it in code instead of xml.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the view , remove it by calling

```
newsListView.removeView(view);
```